# Runtime Switch Crashes MS Access 2013

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I'm using Access 2013 32 bit on Windows 8.1 64bit. I'm attempting to test my application in the runtime mode but it causes Access to crash early in the application start phase. It doesn't appear to matter what code is running as it crashes when I try to open a file that has only tables (no macros, forms, or code modules).

I've tried running Windows Update and there doesn't appear to be any updates available. But when I look to see what updates were installed over the last day or so (I just installed Office 2013 yesterday), I can't tell that any Office updates have been installed.

Has anyone else seen this problem? Any solutions other than using something < 2013?

Comment: With no macros, forms, or code modules, what code can be running when you start Access with the `/RUNTIME` command line switch?

Comment: Well, actually, I first tried it on a database with all of the above, and when that crashed I then tried it on an empty one to make sure it wasn't my code causing the problems.

Comment: I just tried the `/runtime` switch and it seems to be working fine for me: 32-bit Access 2013 (15.0.4551.1006) on 64-bit Windows 7.